# Flutter- best way to handle nested query stream

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm building a chat app and I'm a bit stuck with how to deal with complex nested query by using `stream`.

1. First off fetching all current logged in user's chat room ids and each id has property like `withWhoId`.
2. After that fetch `withWhoId`'s user info to render profile image or user name something like that.
3. Next we need to fetch last sent message context and time to show the user like normal chat app does.
4. Finally, we need to fetch unread messages count. To do that I decided to fetch logged in user's last seen message's timestamp at the incoming room id and retrieve messages sent after the timestamp to save database cost.

I tried to achieve those process with `StreamBuilder` but it looks so nested and I don't think this is the right way. I searched and find `inheritedWidget` or `stream` and `rxdart`. But I would like to make sure how to handle these circumstances.

How can I get all these information more efficiently?
  Or should I reorganize structure or process? Any help is appreciated!